# Footer navbar moves up when clicking on a textbox in an Android environment

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, cordova, textbox, footer

I'm developing an app using jqm and phonegap. In an Android environment, the jqm footer navbar moves up when I click on a textfield. In the iOS environment, this behavior doesn't show up.I am using JQM 1.1.0 and tested with android 2.3. How to solve this behaviour ?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue as you.  The fix was to add this line to respective navbars:

> data-hide-during-focus"" data-tap-toggle="false"

This prevents the unwanted behaviour in a navbar, header, or footer when clicking or tapping on empty space in the HTML